# Fade to another image on hover using JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

The code I'm using works, but if you run your mouse too quickly over the image, it disappears completely.  Doesn't show the image or the one which replaces it on hover.  Just a blank space.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
// Change the image of hoverable images
var openPng = $(".fadeim").attr("src");
var closedPng = openPng.replace(".png", "-hover.png");
$(".fadeim")
    .mouseover(function() {   
        $(this).fadeOut(350,function(){  
            $(this).attr("src", closedPng);  
            $(this).fadeIn(350);  
        });  
    })  
    .mouseout(function() {  
        $(this).fadeOut(350,function(){  
            $(this).attr("src", openPng);  
            $(this).fadeIn(350);           
        });  
    })  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fadeIn("fast")`. You have given time 350 milliseconds which may be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply;  no go unfortunately, same thing still happens.

Comment: I think you should increase the time instead making it `fast`. Try `fadeIn("slow")` or any other grater value. Sorry for previous suggestion.

Comment: Same thing, except this time the image blanks even more quickly.

Comment: I got this URL http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery. It works even when run your mouse too quickly over the image. Check the sample given.

Comment: Works a treat, but doesn't fade.  I was looking specifically for the fade...thanks though

Answer (score 0):

***SCRIPT***

```
$(".imgHolder").mouseenter(function(){
      var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
      $imgs.first().fadeOut('slow');
      $imgs.last().fadeIn('slow');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      var $imgs = $(this).find("img");
      $imgs.first().fadeIn('slow');
      $imgs.last().fadeOut('slow');
    }).find("img").last().hide();
```

***CSS***

```
.imgHolder img {
    position : absolute;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img src="//placekitten.com/200/200"/>
    <img src="//placekitten.com/g/200/200/"/>
</div>
```